# What is the "KEY" when initializing Invoice Ninja Flutter package?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, invoice-ninja

I am trying to use the Invoice Ninja package for flutter.  However, I can't seem to figure out what the "KEY" is?  There is no mention in the docs or settings of any "KEY".  The only mention is API Token.  I have a v5 self hosted instance of Invoice Ninja.

```
invoiceninja: ^0.0.8

InvoiceNinja.configure(
  'KEY', // Set your company key or use 'KEY' to test
  url: 'https://example.com/payments/public', // Set your selfhost app URL
  debugEnabled: true,
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate a company key, in the Invoice Ninja dashboard, navigate to Settings->Client Portal -> Storefront (Enable third-party apps to create invoices), the switch must be on.  This will then show a Company Key.  This has the flutter package working now.